# Ionic-cordova-angularJS syntax meaning?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angular-ui-router, ionic-v1

```
 .state('menu.triptabs', {
      url: '/triptabs',
      abstract: true,
      cache:false,
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/newUIdesign/trip_tabs.html',
          controller: 'MenuCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
```

I am new to ionic-cordova-angular and i found it in app.js so please explain everything clearly. Also there are several controller doing the same task. **How to understand the overall app?**

Comment: That is really a broad question. Is there something specific that you don't understand?

Comment: See [UI-Router Wiki - URL Routing](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing).